# R - Get specific cell in CSV from value in another cell?

Tags: r, database, csv

If I do this

```
data %>% filter(primary.name == "Down syndrome" | other.names == "Down syndrome")
```

I get the whole row of data. But what if I only want the data in one of the cells (ie, the one with the "dx" header)?

I tried this:

```
data$dx %>% filter(primary.name == "Down syndrome" | other.names == "Down syndrome")
```

But got this error:

```
Error in UseMethod("filter_") : 
  no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "factor"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can `pull` the column after the `filter` step

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
  filter(primary.name == "Down syndrome" | other.names == "Down syndrome") %>%
  pull(dx)
```

---

Or another option is `summarise` (which can now return more than one row)

```
data %>%
  summarise(dx = dx[primary.name == "Down syndrome" |
                    other.names == "Down syndrome"]) %>%
  pull(dx)
```

However, it is better to use `filter` for understanding the code

---

If we use

```
data$dx %>%
    ...
```

The `rhs` of `%>%` only gets the value of that column and there is no way it can access the 'primary.name' or 'other.names' column in the dataset

Comment: Thanks so much!! This is the first answer I've gotten from the R community on stack overflow that was really helpful and didn't just berate me!! Will be accepting as an answer.

Comment: Hey quick question - now that I've pulled the data, do you know how to edit it? I posted a question that got heavily downvoted. If you answer there I'll accept your answer for that question as well!

Comment: @G.T. Sure, I will check that out

Comment: @G.T. Please check if the solution posted there works or not.  thanks